# The numerical method used by F.X Wortmann for inverse design

Tags: airfoil

Apologies in advance for a long-winded question.

Can someone who understands some airfoil theory and German language please help me understand the method outlined in [this](https://www.iag.uni-stuttgart.de/dateien/pdf/arbeitsgruppe-laminarwindkanal/Wortmann_ZFW1957.pdf) paper from Prof. FX Wortmann.

I have back-quoted what I've got so far with Google translate but it doesn't appear to be accurate especially with the given context.

[image]

> If you reduce the work of E. Truckenbrodt [8] to calculate the profile shape from the speed distribution to the mere calculation, you come to the following series of formulas: 1. At the n positions of the dimensionless profile depth

[image]

> Table 3 contains the constants bm for N24. The following applies to
>   the pth approximation step
>
> Table 3 contains the constants is the slope of the tangent to the
>   profile shape and results from

[image]

> The values ​​amn are listed in Tables 4 and 5. The values ​​amn for
>   even-numbered m - n disappear. The table amn with m = 2, 4, ... is
>   therefore used to calculate the values ​​y, 'for n = 1, 3, ... A good
>   estimate of the correction values ​​x, which greatly abbreviates the
>   approximation, can be obtained if one starts from the examples already
>   calculated. Eq. (A2) includes (N-1) 2 232 529 operations that can be
>   performed in about two hours with a simple electrical calculator. 2.
>   The skeleton line of a curved profile, in which the speeds on the top
>   of the profile (index o) and underside (index u) are different, is
>   calculated

[image]

> Table 3 contains the constants dmn. The value for z is already known
>   from the above calculation. This skeletal line still needs a minor
>   correction, which is reflected in
>
> The constants pa, qn are given in Table 6. The values ​​y, and are
>   according to Eq. (A2) and (A5) known. The angle of attack a is
>   calculated

[image]

> The values ​​d are also shown in Table 3. The final coordinates of a
>   curved profile then result from (A11) = y (s) 4ys) + y (). The
>   positive sign applies to the top of the profile.

Also with my very limited understanding with possibly incorrect translation, I've got the following questions so far

1. What is the $(t)$ in $\bar{y}_n^{(t)}$ in (A-2)
2. what is the $p^{th}$ approximation in (A-3)
3. What is the $(s)$ in $\bar{y}_n^{(s)}$ in (A-2)
4. Does (A-6) refers to the camber line calculation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is the $(t)$ in $\bar{y}_n^{(t)}$ in (A-2)

The text doesn't say. t in German normally denotes chord (Tiefe), but since we later see $\bar{y}_n^{(s)}$ for the camber line (Skelettlinie), it here stands for Tropfen, denoting the thickness distribution of the uncambered airfoil.

I would also interpret the long dash between $\bar{y}_n^{(t)}$ and the sum in A2 as a misprinted equal sign. Otherways the whole sequence will not add up.

> what is the $p^{th}$ approximation in (A-3)

You mean $p$th, don't you? p is used as the index of a stepwise approximation. $f_m^{(p)}$ is the $p$th iteration of $f_m$.

> What is the $(s)$ in $\bar{y}_n^{(s)}$ in (A-2)

That is only in A 6 and indicates that $\bar{y}_n$ this time denotes the ordinate values for the camber line (see above).

> Does (A-6) refer to the camber line calculation?

Yes.

Comment: "...someone who understands some airfoil theory and German language..." It's like he was looking for you! ;)